Is Tweeting without user input virtually impossible?
Goal: allow my serverless node.js app to post to my own Twitter feed.
Problem: as far as I can tell, there is no way to do this. X/Twitter's Auth option for an app is called "App-only", but it isn't one of the supported methods for tweeting. The only supported methods are OAuth 1.0a and OAuth 2.0. I don't believe that those are intended for app-based authentication, and there is no way for me to manipulate the authentication flow to achieve my goal. Am I correct in reaching that conclusion?
